# Why should I sign in Twitter to use an application I created using Twitter API

Tags: php, twitter

I have developed a Twitter project using Twitter API-PHP(library of abraham). However when I try to open my site, It asks to sign in and to be given permission to use that application by a profile when I clear the session variables.

I want that project to work without asking that permission, what should be done in this case?

Comment: Solution: http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_single_token#your_language

Answer (score 0):

Store the auth tokens in a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

You need to token security code, API code and redirect URL in your account.
You can change or manage them with your account